# What approach should I used to traverse through a binary tree in a side to side manner in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have done a lot of research on how to traverse through binary trees and I still have not found a way to traverse through a tree without going all the way to its leaves. I just want to print the binary tree one level at a time instead of using In-Order-Traversal, Pre-Order-Traversal, or Post-Order-Traversal results.

I want to print: {2, 7, 5, 2, 6, null, 9, null, null, 5, 11, 4, null}. Can I use recursion to solve this? Because it seems like I always end up at the leaves of one side before I solve for the other sides non-leaves.

[image]

Comment: The key phrase here is "breadth first", *if* you go to the leafs first it is called "depth first". Google for how to implement "breadth first".

Comment: What you want won't be a typical binary tree traversal, since traversing is recursive way of visiting (root - leftChild - rightChild), (leftChild - root - rightChild), (leftChild - rightChild - root). And you see that there are no other possibilities there.

Answer (score -1):

In pseudo code:

- Create a queue of nodes (A `Deque` in java, eg `LinkedList`)
- Put the root node on the queue
- While the queue is not empty

  - Take the next node from the head
  - put its children on the end of the queue
  - process the node

Basically, to process *breadth first* (which is what you want), use a *queue*. To process *depth first*, use a stack